# Is $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-3})$ UFD for odd terms?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

It's clear that  $\mathbb{Z}\left({\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}}\right)\supset\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-3})$ .

And that  $\mathbb{Z}\left({\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}}\right)$ is a maximal order and UFD.

I also know that  $4$  in  $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-3})$  is  $(1-\sqrt{-3})(1+\sqrt{-3})$  and that  $2$  it is irreducible but nonprime because doesn't divide  $1\pm\sqrt{-3}$ .

Can I justify any way that  $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-3})$  is a UFD for odd terms?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess it depends on how you phrase it. Write out a definition and see if it makes sense. (The elements $a+b\sqrt{-3}$ with $a^2+3b^2$ odd are what I’d call the odd elements. And yes, they have unique factorization into odd primes.) But the additional question is: why would you define this? Does it get you anything useful?

Comment: Basically, we use the more complicated ring of algebraic integers, rather than $R=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}],$ for a reason. Yeah, I understand the aesthetic reasons we might prefer $R,$ for simplicity, but trying to enforce an aesthetic choice like this doesn’t tend to add much understanding in the long run.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It is useful for demonstrating directly the crucial Lemma that Euler uses in the case of FLT for n=3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An order in a quadratic number field has unique factorization for integers coprime to the conductor if and only if the class number of the corresponding quadratic forms is equal to $1$. If the order has discriminant $df^2$ for a fundamental discriminant $d$, then $f$ is the conductor. In your example, the discriminant of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ is $-12 = -3 \cdot 2^2$, hence the conductor is the ideal $f = (2)$. The class number of (primitive) binary quadratic forms with discriminant $-12$ is $1$ (pari: quadclassunit(-12)). The order ${\mathbb Z}[\sqrt{-11}]$, on the other hand, has class number $3$ (this fact is responsible for the existence of a cubic field with discriminant $-44$ by class field theory).

For a proof using ideal theory see these [notes](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/ant.pdf) by Peter Stevenhagen, in particular Exercise 15 on p. 25.